Why does the order change when using UNION ALL in PostgreSQL?
I am trying to solve this Hackerrank SQL question(https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/the-pads/problem?isFullScreen=true) . (my solution might be not efficient, nevermind)
I have two SQL queries in PostgreSQL that return expected results individually but produce unexpected ordering when combined using UNION ALL.
The first query concatenates the name and the first letter of the occupation, ordered by the name:
SELECT * 
FROM (
    SELECT CONCAT(Name, '(', LEFT(Occupation, 1), ')') 
    FROM OCCUPATIONS 
    ORDER BY Name
) AS sub1;

The result is as expected:
Aamina(D)
Ashley(P)
Belvet(P)
Britney(P)
Christeen(S)
.
.

.
The second query counts the occupations and concatenates the result, ordered by the count of occupations and the first letter of the occupation:
SELECT * 
FROM (
    SELECT CONCAT('There are a total of ', COUNT(Occupation), ' ', LOWER(Occupation), 's.')
    FROM OCCUPATIONS
    GROUP BY Occupation
    ORDER BY COUNT(Occupation), LEFT(Occupation, 1)
) AS sub2;

The result for second query is:
There are a total of 3 doctors.
There are a total of 4 actors.
There are a total of 4 singers.
There are a total of 7 professors.

However, when I combine these two queries using UNION ALL, the order of the first part changes unexpectedly:
    select dest 
from (
    select * from (select 1 as source, concat(Name,'(',LEFT(Occupation,1),')')  as dest
    from OCCUPATIONS 
    order by Name) as a
UNION ALL
    select * from (select 2 as source, concat('There are a total of ',count(Occupation),' ',lower(Occupation),'s.') as dest
    from OCCUPATIONS
    group by Occupation
    order by count(Occupation), left(Occupation,1)) as b
) as comb
order by source;

The combined result is:
Ashley(P)
Samantha(A)
Julia(D)
Britney(P)
There are a total of 3 doctors.
There are a total of 4 actors.
There are a total of 4 singers.
There are a total of 7 professors.

Note that order of first select query is changed. Why is this happening ? Notice that the second query's order is maintained.
I want the results from the first query to maintain their original order when combined with the second query. How can I achieve this?

What happens if you move the ORDER BY outside? SELECT * FROM (...) AS sub1 ORDER BY Name UNION ALL ....

A sub-query ORDER BY doesn't guarantee anything.

I am trying to solve this Hackerrank SQL question ... and, as written, your question has no problem statement.  External links can and often do break over time.

@TimBiegeleisen The question is already fat, waiting to be edited by moderators, if I add the description it will look more ugly. Suggest me what to do or feel free to edit as you may see fit.

The general answer to your question is that the ORDER BYs you have inside the subquery are pointless.  The ordering does not "stick" outside the subqueries.

@TimBiegeleisen I have wrongly pasted my old query while asking the question.  I have updated my combined query. Using this query only I am facing the problem. Can you tell me how order by affects this query.

@DrinkandDerive That would only keep these two from mixing, but each set of rows can still be freely reordered. You'd have to add a row_number()over(order by...), then order by source,row_number in the outer query: demo

Unless you specify an order by in the outer query, its order is accidental, as already pointed out by @Tim Biegeleisen. You can order CTE's and subqueries internally but as long as there's no order by at the final, outer level, the database is free to reorder the rows.
Your idea with establishing a source to order by later makes sense, but that would only stop the two sources from mixing, which is currently unlikely but technically allowed. Their internal order needs to also be passed to the outer query, which you can get with a row_number() window function: demo at db<>fiddle
with a as 
(select 1 as source
      , row_number()over(order by name) as row_number
      , concat(name,'(',left(occupation,1),')') as dest
 from occupations)
,b as 
(select 2 as source
      , row_number()over(order by count(occupation), occupation) as row_number
      , concat('There are a total of '
               ,count(occupation),' '
               ,lower(occupation),'s.') as dest
 from occupations
 group by occupation)
,a_union_b as (select * from a union all select * from b)
select dest 
from a_union_b
order by source,row_number;

There's no need to do left(Occupation,1) in order by count(Occupation), left(Occupation,1) - it's supposed to order rows with the same count alphabetically not just based on the first letter of the occupation.
This works both in PostgreSQL as well as Microsoft SQL Server, only the latter of which you can submit for that exercise.
